# steps for adapt eclipse dynamic web project to have a site in real server

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I wrote a small `servlet` and jsp project on eclipse and `tomcat 5.5`, but I don't know with works I do for make that a real site on a real host. Should I war them or I should upload project on host? My host should have which properties? I really don't now how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend packaging them in a war and deploying it out to the remote tomcat server.  Its not a good idea to deploy an unpackaged project directly to the server unless your debugging or testing.  Once you have a finished project ready to deploy package it to a war.  I typically deploy to server using the tomcat manager page.  Just browse for the war, click the upload button and it should start right up. On my local machine this is the url that I use to upload to the server http://localhost:8080/manager.  The server itself should have the same properties and settings that you are using in your eclipse workspace, and I would highly  recommend that it be the same version as well.  The war can also be dropped into a directory on the remote host and Tomcat will load this on startup, this location will vary depending on the host.